# Derivative of product of inverse matrices

Tags: matrices, derivatives, inverse

My question is as follows:

What is the result of

$\frac{d}{d{\bf X}}{\bf X}^{-1}{\bf C}{\bf X}^{-1}$, where ${\bf X}$ is positive definite (PD), ${\bf C}$ is positive semidefinite (PSD)?

(If possible, please show me a compact result, maybe using Kronecker product)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$F=X^{-1}CX^{-1}$$ Taking the gradient of this matrix with respect to the matrix $X$ results in a 4th order tensor.

The special (isotropic) 4th order tensor ${\mathbb E}$ with components $${\mathbb E}_{ijkl}=\delta_{ik}\,\delta_{jl}$$ can be used in a compact expression for this gradient.

Finding the differential and gradient is straightforward
$$\eqalign{
dF &= \{dX^{-1}\}\,CX + X^{-1}C\,\{dX^{-1}\} \cr
  &= -\,\{X^{-1}\,dX\,X^{-1}\}\,CX^{-1} - X^{-1}C\,\{X^{-1}\,dX\,X^{-1}\} \cr
  &= -\,(X^{-1}\,dX\,F + F\,dX\,X^{-1}) \cr
  &= -\,(X^{-1}\,{\mathbb E}\,F^T + F\,{\mathbb E}\,X^{-T}):dX \cr\cr
\frac{\partial F}{\partial X} &= -\,(X^{-1}\,{\mathbb E}\,F^T + F\,{\mathbb E}\,X^{-T}) \cr
}$$ where colon denotes the [Frobenius Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product).

Another common method for dealing with matrix-by-matrix gradients is to use vectorization and the Kronecker Product 
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(dF) &= -\,{\rm vec}(X^{-1}\,dX\,F + F\,dX\,X^{-1}) \cr
  df &= -\,(F^T\otimes X^{-1}+X^{-T}\otimes F)\,dx \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= -\,(F^T\otimes X^{-1}+X^{-T}\otimes F) \cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks! The result is ideal for me, though I cannot fully understand how you get it. If there is any reference talking about this kind of derivative? (I mean, the derivative of a matrix and the chain's rule in this case...)

Comment: As an online reference, you might start with the [Matrix Cookbook](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi//matrixcookbook.pdf).  If you want a physical book, try "Matrix Differential Calculus" by Magnus and Neudecker (3rd ed, ISBN:0-471-98632-1)